# Stop javascript loading into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this javascript code set up which loads the contents of a HTML page into my div #mid. This does it by default for ALL links on my website no matter where pressed. However, I want to link to an external website and don't want the javascript to load this into the div, I want it to open in a new tab.

```
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
// Configuration
divID = '#mid';
loadingHTML = 'Loading..';
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $(divID).load('pages/home.html');
});
</script>
```

To load links I just use:

```
<a href="pages/services.html"></a>
```

How can I stop it loading into the div for certain links which I choose? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have some sort of a way of telling which links you want to open in the div and which ones you want to open in a new tab.

For this example, I will use `.internal` as loading into the div and `.external` as loading in a new tab.

The `window.open(url)` function is what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.internal").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        $(divId).load($(this).attr("href"));

    });

    $("a.external").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr("href"));

    });

});
```

---

So an internal-loading link would look like this:

```
<a href="/pages/somePage.html" class="internal">An Internal Link</a>
```

And an external link would look like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="external">An External Link to Google</a>
```

Comment: I've tried this out but I haven't been able to get it to work (most likely my own fault). Could you help me some more? My website is www.GTDiscos.com